# How to connect Oracle with odp.net without install Oracle client

Tags: .net, odp.net, oracleclient

I install ODAC12c and add "Oracle.DataAccess.dll" reference to my project. I can run it fine on my machine.

But Is it possible to run this project on other machine without install Oracle client?

Which dll file that I need to copy to my project?

Comment: you'll need the instant client, at least. Instant client doesn't need any installation

Comment: I download it and extract then add PATH in environment. but it's say unable to load oraops12.dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver you do need the set of DLLs contained in the client. An easy way to achieve this is to use the XCOPY download to embed it with your application.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

If you are in the early phase of development, you could consider using ODP.NET, Managed Driver instead which is less than 10 MB in size and is one or two DLLs). It is missing a few features that the Unmanaged driver has.